# Polymorphic many to many categories with nested related child categories

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've been trying to figure out how to get polymorphic many to many categories with nested related child to load in. E.g. products with categories and child categories that have the same categorizable_id in the pivot table as the product id.

This is what I have so far, the categories relation works find as does children only when I'm trying to do it on a product it does not:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'categorizable')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Category model:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Product::class, 'categorizable');
    }

    public function children(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Migrations:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->string('context');
    $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});

Schema::create('categorizables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->morphs('categorizable');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Im trying all sorts but cant figure it out e.g.:

```php
$product->categories()->with(['children' => function($q) use ($product) {
    return $q->where(categorizable_id, $product->id);
}])->get();

$product->categories()->with(['children' => function($q) use ($product) {
    return $q->wherePivot('categorizable.categorizable_id', $product->id);
}])->get();
```

I've also tried lots of different whereHas. I want to be able to have this as a scope or something similar so it's very easy to get the categories and the nested child categories that relate to the same model as the parent category ID.

Any help would be amazing!